# Square of double variable is always positive?

Tags: floating-point, double

Double data type, d and float data type f exist.
1) d*d is always greater than or equal to 0.0?
2) (f+d)-f is always equal to d?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question should mention a programming language. Since it doesn't, we can only answer according to the rules of the IEEE 754 floating-point standard, and the programming language may not map its construct to that of IEEE 754 as exactly as you would want.

1) a floating-point values can be finite, infinite or NaN. For finite and infinite values, the usual rule of signs applies: - * - produce + and + * + produce +, so that for a finite or infinite `d`, we have `d * d ≥ 0`. If `d` is NaN, then `d * d` is `NaN`, and the value `NaN` is not greater than or equal to 0

2) `(f + d) - f` is not equal to `d` for most values of `d` and `f`. One example is f = 2<sup>100</sup> and d = 1. For these values `(f + d) - f` is 0. The issue can be seen even with values of `f` and `d` that are closer to each other, for instance f = 10 and d = 0.1. With these values, `f + d` is a number close to 10. With a fixed number of significant binary digits, the space taken to represent `10.…` does not allow to keep all the binary digits that are present in the representation of `0.1`. Subtracting 10 again from that reveals the binary digits have have been lost during the addition.

Comment: You do not comment on the fact that f is float and d is double, but I don't think it would make any difference in your answer. In the languages I know that have both float and double, f will be converted to double and the arithmetic done in double.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And I use C language !

Comment: But if d==1, f==2^100, then (f+d)==2^100 (because d is too small?), so (f+d)-f==0.
The Uncertainty of d and f is relative?

Comment: @주혜민 Yes. IEEE 754 double-precision (C type `double` in most compilers) can only represent bits with weight from 2^100 to 2^48 (53 binary digits). If one tries to add a quantity smaller than 2^48 to 2<sup>100</sup>, all the digits of the smaller quantity are lost. If one tries to add a quantity around 2^80 to 2^100, then the 20 binary digits of lowest weight of the smaller quantity may be lost.